# Getting spotify desktop player status

Tags: spotify, spotify-desktop

I come from an electronics background, with a project whereby I'd like to be able to obtain various information about the state of the desktop player, eg

- Current track name
- Current track artist
- Position in song
- Play/pause status

Is there an active API or other method which will allow me to obtain this information and get it out of the desktop app itself, such that I might be able to send that information out via a COM port?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my .NET Library [SpotifyAPI .NET](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET)

It combines the spotify-local and spotify-web API.
Also, it provides all your required information and is simple to use.
Small example:

```
SpotifyLocalAPIClass spotify = new SpotifyLocalAPIClass();

if(!spotify.Connect())
    return;

SpotifyMusicHandler mh = spotify.GetMusicHandler();
SpotifyEventHandler eh = spotify.GetEventHandler();

Console.WriteLine(mh.GetCurrentTrack().GetTrackName());
```